# Counter that rotates that is safe for concurrent use

Tags: go

I want to write something like this:

```
type RoundRobinList struct {
    lst []string
    idx uint32
}

// rr_list is a RoundRobinList
func loop(rr_list) {
   start = rr_list.idx
   rr_list.idx = (rr_list.idx + 1)%len(rr_list.lst)
   print(rr_list.lst[idx])
}
```

If rr_list.lst = ["a", "b", "c"], and loop is called over and over, I would expect the following printed:

"a"
"b"
"c"
"a"
"b"
"c" ...

Is this safe? rr_list.idx = (rr_list.idx + 1)%len(rr_list.lst)

Comment: The statement `rr_list.idx = (rr_list.idx + 1)%len(rr_list.lst)` is not safe for concurrent execution. Use a [mutex](https://godoc.org/sync#Mutex) to protect access to the idx field.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a read and write of a value that's not protected in some way (using a mutex, or some of the other things in the `sync` package), you have a race, and that means you can't use it safely in a concurrent setting.

Here, you're reading and writing the `idx` field of your `RoundRobinList` structure without any protection, so you'll have a race if you use it concurrently.

As a first line of defense you should understand the rules for memory safety and follow them carefully, and not write code unless you're pretty sure it's safe. As a second line of defense, you can use the race detector to find a lot of problems with lack of safety of concurrent access.

Here's a simple test case, in file `a_test.go`. I had to also fix some bugs in the code to get it to compile. It starts two goroutines which call `loop` 1000 times each on a shared `RoundRobinList`.

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "testing"
)

type RoundRobinList struct {
    lst []string
    idx uint32
}

func loop(rr *RoundRobinList) {
    rr.idx = (rr.idx + 1) % uint32(len(rr.lst))
}

func TestLoop(t *testing.T) {
    rr := RoundRobinList{[]string{"a", "b", "c"}, 0}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    for n := 0; n < 2; n++ {
        go func() {
            for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
                loop(&rr)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Running with `go test -race ./a_test.go` results in:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0000b0078 by goroutine 9:
  command-line-arguments.loop()
      /mnt/c/Users/paul/Desktop/a_test.go:14 +0xa1
  command-line-arguments.TestLoop.func1()
      /mnt/c/Users/paul/Desktop/a_test.go:24 +0x78

Previous write at 0x00c0000b0078 by goroutine 8:
  command-line-arguments.loop()
      /mnt/c/Users/paul/Desktop/a_test.go:14 +0x4e
  command-line-arguments.TestLoop.func1()
      /mnt/c/Users/paul/Desktop/a_test.go:24 +0x78

Goroutine 9 (running) created at:
  command-line-arguments.TestLoop()
      /mnt/c/Users/paul/Desktop/a_test.go:22 +0x1cc
  testing.tRunner()
      /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:992 +0x1eb

Goroutine 8 (finished) created at:
  command-line-arguments.TestLoop()
      /mnt/c/Users/paul/Desktop/a_test.go:22 +0x1cc
  testing.tRunner()
      /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:992 +0x1eb
==================
--- FAIL: TestLoop (0.00s)
    testing.go:906: race detected during execution of test
FAIL
FAIL    command-line-arguments  0.006s
FAIL
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I have heard of  atomic.AddInt32(&rr.idx, 1) but I am not sure if there is something similar to that for the modulus operator